# How to dynamically create a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, function, variables, eval

I have a predefined pattern for building a string, which should be created regularly throughout the script.

```
$str="$first - $second @@ $third"; // pattern for building the string
$first="word1";
$second="word2";
$third="word3";
$string= ..?? // string should be built here based on the pattern
```

Currently, I am using `eval` to generate the string in place based on the pattern originally defined. However, as this happens occasionally and `eval` is generally bad, I wish to find another method.

NOTE that the pattern is defined only one time above all codes, and I can edit the pattern of all the script by one line only. Thus, ***what makes `$string` should not be touched for any change***.

I tried `create_function`, but needs the same number of arguments. With `eval`, I can easily change the pattern, but with `create-function`, I need to change the entire script. For example, if changing the string pattern to

```
$str="$first @@ $second"; // One arg/var is dropped
```

**eval Example:**

```
$str="$first - $second @@ $third"; // Pattern is defined one-time before codes
$first="word1";
$second="word2";
$third="word3";
eval("\$string = \"$str\";");
```

**create_function Example:**

```
$str=create_function('$first,$second,$third', 'return "$first - $second @@ $third";');
$string=$str($first,$second,$third);
```

Comment: Could you give your example with `eval` please? It's a little difficult to understand what exactly you're trying to do, since the last string declaration looks like it should work for what you want.

Comment: @Vulcan I added the examples to clarify the issue.

Comment: Thanks, they helped clarify your question quite a bit, and I've answered the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the string formatting capabilities offered by [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or [`vsprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php).

```
$format = "%s - %s @@ %s"; // pattern for building the string
$first = "word1";
$second = "word2";
$third = "word3";
$string = sprintf($format, $first, $second, $third);
```

You can use `vsprintf` if you wish to pass an array.

```
$format = "%s - %s @@ %s"; // pattern for building the string
$values = array($first, $second, $third);
$string = vsprintf($format, $values);
```

Comment: subtle solution, but what if changing the order of variables in the pattern? for example: `$str="$second-$first"`; then, we need to change the `sprintf` pattern too throughout the script.

Comment: You can specify in the format what argument number to refer to: `$str = "%2$s-%1$s"`. That would place the second (third including the $format itself) argument before the first in the output order.

Comment: Now, it's a practical solution. I appreciate your subtle view to mention `sprintf`, which is the key function for patterning strings, but I blindly ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be rather simple thing to me. Use `str_replace()` and replace based on patterns

```
$str="$first$ - $second$ @@ $third$"; // pattern for building the string
$first="word1";
$second="word2";
$third="word3";

$newstr = str_replace('$first$', $first, $str);
$newstr = str_replace('$second$', $second, $newstr);
$newstr = str_replace('$third$', $third, $newstr);
```

Comment: 1. The pattern is not always simple, 2. I want to make change only to the pattern, but by your method, I need to modify `$newstr` throughout the script, and many many times.

Answer (score 0):

This might help, not sure.

```
$str = "_first_ - _second_ @@ _third_"; // pattern for building the string
// _first, _second_... are placeholders for actual values

// this function performs the string building
function buildString( $arr ) {
   global $str;

   $keys = array_keys( $arr );
   $vals = array_values( $arr );

   return eval( str_replace( $keys, $vals, $str ) );
}

while(some condition here) {
    $str = 'A new string'; // you can change your string builiding pattern here

    // this array is built in the fashion ->
    // keys of array are the variables in $str and
    // their actual values are the values of $str
    $arr=array('_first_' => $first, '_second_' => $second, '_third_' => $third);
    echo buildString( $arr );
}
```

Comment: Currently, `eval` works perfectly. The point is that `eval` is not a good thing. I want to do this without `eval`, but your function is based on `eval` too.